# Couchbase: 1 MB size exceeded for value in index view

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I see that value in view has exceeded 1 MB size (it is 1.7 MB) and thereby not getting emitted in views. I have tried to change values of `max_kv_size_per_doc` in `default.ini` (then restarted couchbase) but still value is not getting emitted.

Could someone please suggest workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couchbase view index update hanging after adding file over ~1.4mb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609638/couchbase-view-index-update-hanging-after-adding-file-over-1-4mb)

Answer (score 1):

Yes: dont emit documents in views - its not a recommended practice. In fact, by emitting docs in views you're creating a copy of the doc on your storage (== bad). 100 docs + view that returns them = 200 docs's space.

Instead, emit keys for docs and retrieve them after you get the results from the view. or just emit the part of the doc that you need (if its smallish).

edit: i'm guessing you havn't tried the "include_docs" options? it should attach the complete doc to your results without creating a duplicate.